# Preventing MVC annotations to be processed by JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am building JUnit tests for my web application.

Part of these tests work on MVC controllers, so that the tests are annotated with `@WebAppConfiguration` which is correct. Other tests, however, work on backend resoruces that have nothing to see with the web context (in general, these components are designed in order to be able to run outside of a web context, with a simple Spring context).

Now that I am writing this question I also think that my problem with JUnit will reappear very soon when I will start my application in a non-web context, but better go step by step.

My test class is annotated with

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = CustomContextInitializer.class,
        locations =
        {
                "classpath:META-INF/context/data-context.xml",
                "classpath:META-INF/context/web-context.xml" //Nothing to do with MVC, don't be fooled by name. No web resource here
        })
```

However when I start the test I get an error about loading ApplicationContext

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at [redacted for brevity]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'navigateController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; [redacted for brevity]
    at [redacted for brevity]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest org.example.controllers.Controller.httpServletRequest; [redacted for brevity]
    at [redacted for brevity]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at [redacted for brevity]
```

I have redacted all traces for brevity.

The problem is **simple**: my classpath contains classes annotated with `@Controller`. At least one of them is bound to the `HttpServletContext` which is required.

I would like to tell Spring, at least now in JUnit environment, to skip MVC-related annotations when loading the context. I can skip all those beans. Basically I need to separate the data context (that contains only DB related classes and data access objects) from the web context (containing data managers implementing business logic) from the MVC context (containing web controllers and resources).

The XML file contains directive `<context:component-scan base-package="org.example" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tag `context:component-scan` allows to set inclusion and exclusion filters.

In order to separate the components being scanned by mutliple context files, do the following.

Context A (everything except controllers)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Context B (remaining controllers)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>
```